# "wide character in print" causing cpan install failure

Tags: perl, cpan, strawberry-perl

I have installed and used a module, [MARC::Charset](http://search.cpan.org/~gmcharlt/MARC-Charset-1.35/lib/MARC/Charset.pm), on linux and OS x successfully. However, it is not installing correctly using Strawberry Perl. The "wide character in print" error occurrs frequently throughout the build log, specifically  when it is trying to build its char conversion table.

"Wide character in print" has plagued me a few times on Windows, but I was always able to work it out as it was occurring in my own scripts. Now however it is occurring (if I understand correctly) in the module's build script....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** 2015-12-29: It looks like it's building on 5.22.1 64bit.

---

It appears that MARC::Charset has been [failing to build on the last few releases of Perl on Windows](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=MARC-Charset+1.35).  It also appears as though nobody has [opened a ticket about the issue](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=MARC-Charset), though the developers should theoretically be informed by CPAN Testers (the 1st site).

Possible courses of action:

- Be a productive member of the community!

  - File a bug report.
  - Modify the scripts to handle unicode output on windows correctly.  Bonus points for sending your diffs along with your bug report.
- Just solve your problem!

  - <strike>*Force* install the module, ignoring the errors in the test scripts.  Do your own testing to see if it meets your needs.</strike>  OP tried this one and it didn't work for this module. =(
  - Move your program to a *nix based OS.  OS X & Linux are both popular and seem to be building/installing the module just fine.
  - Look over the [perldelta](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-history.html)s and decide if any of it is important to your needs.  If not, feel free to use an older release of Perl.

P.S.  As MARC::Charset hasn't seen an update in a couple years, it's entirely possible this module has become unsupported.  Best of luck!

Comment: thanks. older versions of Starbwerry Perl are still available on their website. would it reasonable to try with an older version?

Comment: I think it would be reasonable to look over the [perldelta](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-history.html)s and decide if any of it is important to your needs.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I did force install. The module is in fact installed... it's just that the char tables it needs to do the conversions never complied

Comment: @beasy FWIW: I just got MARC::Charset to build on Strawberry Portable 5.22.1.1-64bit .